# How to make javascript debugger enable in firefox

Tags: asp.net, debugging, firefox

Say you have javascript code sample like below in asp.net page body onload event.

```
function OnloadHandler()
{
    ...
    debugger;
    ...
}
```

We know when run this in IE ,the `debugger` just like a break-point , and wait for us to debug . But when I run it in Firefox . The code `debugger;` didn't work. I had to manually to set a break-point with Firebug.
Can anyone tell me how to make `debugger` enabled in Firefox? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Firebug the `debugger;` keyword should work whenever the execution reaches it:

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Debugger;_keyword